# Insert UTF-8 into DB2 in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, db2

I had `stringConnect`:

```
DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;
HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;
```

Table in DB2 was setup **CCSID UNICODE**.

**DB2** chcp set 65001, code page 1208, code set **UTF-8**.

Here my query:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('Tấn');
```

But in Table displayed:

[image]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your database connection ist set to ISO codepage (819 at DB2).
If I´m right, db2_client_info() says exactly that.

You have to use your DB2-Command and connect to your database

```
db2 connect to xyzdb
db2set DB2CODEPAGE=1208
db2 connect reset
db2stop
db2start
```

Codepage 1208 is UTF-8. After that db2_client_info() should reflect that codepage is changed